# dynamic obstacle problems with short range sensor

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I got some problem in using move_base with short LaserScan sensor.

Here is my condition:

- With short distance range sensor  (xv11 sensor, max range is 6M)
- With a static map and the map contains lots of open space
- Now I put an obstacle in front of the robot. Yes, I saw the obstacle shown in costmap.
- Then, I removed the above obstacle from gazebo.
- I found the obstacle is still there in costmap. I think it's because the range sensor can not reach the edge of the map,
  so it got unknown readings for this area which I put an obstacle in previous step.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Kevin Kuei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220058/dynamic-obstacle-problems-with-short-range-sensor/) by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2015-10-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-10-28**:
what is your raytrace_range parameter set to in the costmap?

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-10-28**:
raytrace_range=2.5 and obstacle_range=2.0, I put the obstacle at 1.5m in front and I saw the obstacle in costmap. Then, I removed the obstacle from gazebo. But the result is, the obstacle is still in costmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Again, I will answer my own question.

I wrote a custom range filter, and this can be applied in obstacle observation sources in costmap_common_params.yaml
The logic is simple, if the laser range is large enough or Inf or Nan, then rewrite it to be another value which is slightly larger than your "obstacle_range" value.

https://github.com/wennycooper/learning_nav/blob/master/src/mybot_laser_obstacle_clearing_filter.cpp

---

Originally posted by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) with karma: 159 on 2015-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1